# Showing Attributes Bundle Products Magento Community 1.9.1

Tags: magento-1.9, bundle, bundle-product

Looking at the Bundled product template `select.phtml`, I cannot figure how to pull in the attribute options in the '`dropdown`' select input type that distinguishes between children (Simple products) rather than the Product Name (by default). In Configurable products this is the super_configurable_attribute so what I'm looking to do is something like a `super_bundle_attribute` which displays the relative attribute option.

```
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/select.phtml
```

How I would need to change this in Magento CE 1.9?

Comment: There is no thing such as attributes related to bundle products, you can bundle anything in a bundle option independent from attributes.

Comment: You are incorrect fschmengler, the Parent > Child relationship is derived from 'attributes' - so the origination of this question/request wasn't necessarily programmatic but rather how to get the data to display in such a way that more resembles a super_configurable_attribute...in this case, I have the parent > child relationship but also have an additional child (demo product) I don't want included in the dropdown.

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood you then, and you were talking about the bundle options, which are technically not attributes and, more important, do not have names per simple product, they contain only relations to the simple products. Maybe the question will be more clear if you give an example.

Comment: Here's an example of in the cart: take.ms/GsgtQ - and here's the product page dropdown: http://take.ms/iChcQ -

Answer (score 0):

I actually played around with this for a while and thanks to this post: [Magento Bundle - Get attribute of option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978585/magento-bundle-get-attribute-of-option/29179179#29179179) I was able to figure this out, the code change was from (native 1.9.1 select.phtml template):

`<?php echo $this->getSelectionTitlePrice($_selection, false) ?></option>`

to

`<?php $bundledsize = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_selection->getId())->getAttributeText('your_custom_attribute'); 
            echo $bundledsize; ?>`

Comment: Best Magento Magento practices would be using 'getSingleton' rather than using 'getModel', from a performance perspective > getModel is bad practice, the end result is: <option value="<?php echo $_selection->getSelectionId() ?>"<?php if ($this->_isSelected($_selection)) echo ' selected="selected"' ?><?php if (!$_selection->isSaleable()) echo ' disabled="disabled"' ?>><?php $bundledsize = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($_selection->getId())->getAttributeText('your_custom_attribute'); 
            echo $bundledsize; ?></option>

Comment: No, getSingleton would only result in unwanted side effects and not resolve the best practice violations to not load a model in a template and especially to not load a model in a loop. Using getSingleton covers the violation from code sniffers at most, but doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Hi fschmengler, then what would you use?

Comment: And while I'm at it....how would I get this custom_attribute that I successfully called in the template to show in the cart as shown here: http://take.ms/GsgtQ -